AppImage command line arguments do not work and show command not found on Ubuntu 24.04
I can launch any AppImage on my ubuntu 24.04 LTS device. I tried to use command line arguments but none of them work and i always get command not found message.
As they say, it should work without any problem. https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit#appimage-usage
Examples:
$ anyappimage.AppImage --appimage-help
anyappimage.AppImage: command not found

$ sudo ./anyappimage.AppImage --appimage-extract
sudo: ./anyappimage.AppImage: command not found

I also read these but not helpful:

Why am I unable to install AppImages on a brand new Kubuntu 18.04 install?
How can I create a desktop entry for an AppImage? (although this's an unrelated question. I tried an appimage mentioned in it https://appimage.github.io/Inkscape/)


Where is anyappimage.AppImage located? AFAIK (like any other executable program) if it is not on your current PATH then you will need to specify the full (absolute or relative) path to it

@steeldriver Download folder and If i execute ls; i can see the appimage.

regardless of whether you can see it with ls, if the Download folder is not in your PATH you will need to specify it i.e. ./anyappimage.AppImage - see for example Why do I need to type ./ before executing a program in the current directory?

@steeldriver I already did that. Please see the details above. sudo ./anyappimage.AppImage --appimage-extract. I only have this problem with appimages otherwise i can execute dpkg, sh etc without any problem.

So is anyappimage.AppImage the correct architecture for your hardware? Check with file ./anyappimage.AppImage and uname -m

What do you mean by 24.04+ ??   Release details do matter, as security changes; and 24.10 & later are part of the two year development cycle for Ubuntu 26.04 LTS thus 24.04+ makes no sense??  The release of 24.04 is only the started point of the 26.04 LTS development; with freedom to move away from that as 24.04 was the prior cycle.

@guiverc sorry, 24.04 and 24.10 (i tested on both)

Ubuntu 24.10 (oracular) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu oracular and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 3 October 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 10 October 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/oracular-oriole-release-schedule/36460  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu oracular you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)   Only 24.04 is a stable & supported product on this site; so any reference to 24.10 isn't on-topic here

If you wish to report bugs on unreleased products (Ubuntu oracular which will become 24.10 soon!), firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues, and please note the release is still in beta

@steeldriver I'm testing this now on 24.04 and let's use this appimage to avoid confusions. https://inkscape.org/release/1.3.2/gnulinux/ and i can manually launch that appimage well
--- (1)
file ./Inkscape-091e20e-x86_64.AppImage -->
./Inkscape-091e20e-x86_64.AppImage: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9fdbc145689e0fb79cb7291203431012ae8e1911, stripped
-- (2)
uname -m -->
x86_64

@minjs so you can launch that one, but what about one you are not able to run?

i can launch any appimage by double-click on it and i mean can not use command line arguments. Don't worry. according to the community, it seems like my side issue and i'm downloading new 24.04 iso from ubuntu.com to test on a vm. If this is current device issue, i can repair or reinstall OS
